# how to pass DistortMethod?

Tags: c, lua, ffi, luajit

I have been using ImageMagick's C API called [MagickWand](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php). In [MagickDistortImage](https://www.imagemagick.org/api/magick-image.php#MagickDistortImage), I don't know how to pass second argument. Below is my code.

**lib.lua**

```
ffi.cdef([[  typedef void MagickWand;
  MagickBooleanType MagickDistortImage(MagickWand *wand, const DistortMethod method, const size_t, const double *args, const MagickBooleanType bestfit);
]])
```

**image.lua**

```
local arg = ffi.new("const double[?]",{115.23})
local tt =  handle_result(self, lib.MagickDistortImage(self.wand, Plane2CylinderDistortion, 1, arg, 1))
```

In my above code I don't know how to pass second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. `const DistortMethod method`, it accepts enums so I just need to defined it as integer and pass the integer value. So I modified my code to.

**lib.lua**

```
ffi.cdef([[  
typedef void MagickWand;
typedef const int DistortMethod;
MagickBooleanType MagickDistortImage(MagickWand *wand, DistortMethod method, const size_t, const double *args, const MagickBooleanType bestfit);
]])
```

**image.lua**

```
local arg = ffi.new("const double[?]",{115.23})
--here 10 is used for 'plane2cylinder' method
local tt =  handle_result(self, lib.MagickDistortImage(self.wand, 10, 1, arg, 1))
```